# Parallel Computing - Shuffle

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, performance, parallel-processing, shuffle

I am looking to shuffle an array in parallel. I have found that doing an algorithm similar to bitonic sort but with a random (50/50) re-order results in an equal distribution but only if the array is a power of 2. I've considered the Yates Fisher Shuffle but I can't see how I could parallel-ize it in order to avoid O(N) computations.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good clear recent paper on this [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03167) and the references, especially Shun et al 2015 are worth a read.

But basically you can do this using the same sort of approach that's used in `sort -R`: shuffle by giving each row a random key value and sorting on that key.  And there are lots of ways to do good parallel distributed sort.

Here's a basic version in python + MPI using an odd-even sort; it goes through P communication steps if P is the number of processors.  You can do better than that, but this is pretty simple to understand; it's discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633916/how-does-mpi-odd-even-sort-work).

```python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import random
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

def exchange(localdata, sendrank, recvrank):
    """
    Perform a merge-exchange with a neighbour;
    sendrank sends local data to recvrank,
    which merge-sorts it, and then sends lower
    data back to the lower-ranked process and
    keeps upper data
    """
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    assert rank == sendrank or rank == recvrank
    assert sendrank < recvrank

    if rank == sendrank:
        comm.send(localdata, dest=recvrank)
        newdata = comm.recv(source=recvrank)
    else:
        bothdata = list(localdata)
        otherdata = comm.recv(source=sendrank)
        bothdata = bothdata + otherdata
        bothdata.sort()
        comm.send(bothdata[:len(otherdata)], dest=sendrank)
        newdata = bothdata[len(otherdata):]
    return newdata

def print_by_rank(data, rank, nprocs):
    """ crudely attempt to print data coherently """
    for proc in range(nprocs):
        if proc == rank:
            print(str(rank)+": "+str(data))
            comm.barrier()
    return

def odd_even_sort(data):
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    nprocs = comm.Get_size()
    data.sort()
    for step in range(1, nprocs+1):
        if ((rank + step) % 2) == 0:
            if rank < nprocs - 1:
                data = exchange(data, rank, rank+1)
        elif rank > 0:
            data = exchange(data, rank-1, rank)
    return data

def main():
    # everyone get their data
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    nprocs = comm.Get_size()
    n_per_proc = 5
    data = list(range(n_per_proc*rank, n_per_proc*(rank+1)))

    if rank == 0:
        print("Original:")
    print_by_rank(data, rank, nprocs)

    # tag your data with random values
    data = [(random.random(), item) for item in data]

    # now sort it by these random tags
    data = odd_even_sort(data)

    if rank == 0:
        print("Shuffled:")
    print_by_rank([x for _, x in data], rank, nprocs)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Running gives:

```
$ mpirun -np 5 python mergesort_shuffle.py
Original:
0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
3: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
4: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

Shuffled:
0: [19, 17, 4, 20, 9]
1: [23, 12, 3, 2, 8]
2: [14, 6, 13, 15, 1]
3: [11, 0, 22, 16, 18]
4: [5, 10, 21, 7, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the multi-threaded shuffling in C++ with OpenMP. It uses a slow STL random number generator - you can gain performance by replacing it with `xorshitf+`. For primitive types in `T` (e.g., `int64_t` on 64-bit CPUs), you can replace the locks with `std::compare_exchange_weak()` calls.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>

namespace detail {

template <typename F>
struct FinalAction {
  FinalAction(F&& f) : clean_{std::move(f)} {}
  ~FinalAction() {
    if (enabled_) clean_();
  }
  void Disable() { enabled_ = false; };

 private:
  F clean_;
  bool enabled_{true};
};

}  // namespace detail

template <typename F>
detail::FinalAction<F> Finally(F&& f) {
  return detail::FinalAction<F>(std::move(f));
}

template <typename T>
void ParallelShuffle(T* data, const size_t count) {
  const uint32_t nThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  std::atomic_flag* syncs = static_cast<std::atomic_flag*>(malloc(count * sizeof(std::atomic_flag)));
  auto clean_syncs = Finally([&]() { free(syncs); });
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nThreads)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    new (syncs + i) std::atomic_flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT);
  }

  const size_t nPerThread = (count + nThreads - 1) / nThreads;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nThreads)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, count - 1);
    const size_t iFirst = nPerThread * i;
    const size_t iLimit = std::min(nPerThread + iFirst, count);
    if (iLimit <= iFirst) {
      continue;
    }
    for (size_t j = iFirst; j < iLimit; j++) {
      const size_t fellow = dist(rng);
      if (fellow == j) {
        continue;
      }
      const size_t sync1 = std::min(j, fellow);
      const size_t sync2 = std::max(j, fellow);
      while (syncs[sync1].test_and_set(std::memory_order_acq_rel)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
      }
      while (syncs[sync2].test_and_set(std::memory_order_acq_rel)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
      }
      std::swap(data[sync1], data[sync2]);
      syncs[sync2].clear(std::memory_order_release);
      syncs[sync1].clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
  }
}
```